# Visual studio Python extension mixed mode debugging on CMake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, python-extensions

I'm trying to create a C++ Python extension using pybind11 and CMake, and would like to take advantage of visual studio's mixed mode debugging ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)) for developing the extension.

I tried following the [MSDN guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), and was able to create an extension and debug it using visual studio solution configurations. However, trying to recreate the project with CMake and debug it, breakpoints inside the C++ code are not triggered. I tried recreating the project twice:

1. a full CMake project (i.e. first create a folder with a CMake file then open it in VS).
2. a Python solution with a CMake subproject (adding the build folder to python search paths to access the extension).

In both methods C++ breakpoints are not triggered. Is there any way to make this work? Something I'm missing? I know there is a VSCode plugin which enables something similar. I'm currently using it, however I'd like to know if it is possible in Visual Studio proper.

Versions:

1. Visual Studio 2022
2. CMake 3.18
3. Python 3.8 (with debug symbols installed), however this is not the Python distributed with Visual Studio

Comment: looks like this feature was queued long time ago. Did you find a workaround or solution? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/enable-mixed-mode-debugging-in-cmakeopenfolder-pro/351740

Comment: Not in Visual Studio. I ended up using VSCode with this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug